# Common Lisp quote behavior with car and cdr

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, cdr

Beginner with Lisp.  I'm working through "Common Lisp: A gentle introduction" and I ran into this behavior that I don't understand.  This is in clisp:

```
[57]> (cdar '((fee fi) '(fo fum)))
(FI)
[58]> (cdar '('(fee fi) '(fo fum)))
((FEE FI))
```

The first expression (line 57) makes sense to me.  It's getting the CDR of the CAR of ((fee fi) (fo fum)), ie the CDR of (fee fi).  But what's going in on line 58?  I would have expected it to give me the exact same thing, (FI).  But instead it gave me a list of a list?  Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Even more surprising, if I do each of these in two expressions, I get an error when the (fee fi) is unquoted:

```
[72]> (car '((fee fi) '(fo fum)))
(FEE FI)
[73]> (cdr (FEE FI))

*** - EVAL: undefined function FEE
```

But I get the right result when (fee fi) is quoted, an inversion of my first result:

```
[77]> (car '('(fee fi) '(fo fum)))
'(FEE FI)
[78]> (cdr '(FEE FI))
(FI)
```

Any illumination would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

The `'` character is just an abbreviation: `'something` is expanded at read time to `(quote something)`. Therefore:

```
(cdar '('(fee fi) '(fo fum)))
```

is actually:

```
(cdar (quote ((quote (fee fi)) (quote (fo fum)))))
```

The first `quote` prevents evaluation of its contents, so the rest of them are just literal lists and symbols, so a more useful representation would be:

```
(cdar '((quote (fee fi)) (quote (fo fum))))
```

The `CAR` is then `(quote (fee fi))`, and the `CDR` of that is `((fee fi))`.

Answer (score 1):

Before something can be evaluated by a Lisp, it must be *read in* first. [*`Read`*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm#read) operation takes a textual representation of some datum and turns it into a Lisp datum.

```
[6]> (read)
'a                    ; I typed this
'A                    ; CLISP responded
[7]> (type-of *)      ; * is previous-value
CONS
[8]> (mapcar #'print **) ; ** is value before previous value

QUOTE                 ; first element of the list (code form), (QUOTE A)
A                     ; second element of the list
'A                    ; CLISP translates (QUOTE A) back into 'A, for show
```

So `' ...` is turned into `(quote ...)`, on read. How does this work?

```
[4]> (get-macro-character #\')
#<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SYSTEM::QUOTE-READER> ;
NIL
```

So [there *is* something there behind the quote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_ma.htm). A `quote-reader` system function. Lists are also something special:

```
[5]> (get-macro-character #\()
#<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SYSTEM::LPAR-READER> ;
NIL
```

When all is read, the result is then evaluated. That's the *"read-eval"* part of the *"read-eval-print loop"*, the REPL. The result of evaluating [a *quote* form](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm), `(quote ...)`, is whatever is inside it. IOW the top `quote` disappears, but all the inner `quote`s remain.

Without the quote, everything is evaluated. So to evaluate `(cdr (FEE FI))`, the form `(FEE FI)` must be evaluated, and if it results in a list, that list's `cdr` will be returned.

---

You could [try to define](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_add.htm) another way of representing literal data, say with `[ ... ]` brackets standing for `(quote ( ... ))`. The conversion could treat the *inner* brackets as simple parentheses. Then both

```
> (cdar [(fee fi) (fo fum)])
> (cdar [[fee fi] [fo fum]])
```

would behave the same, as you expected.

PS. CLHS is your friend.

---

edit: here's where you've erred. In your last example,

```
[77]> (car '('(fee fi) '(fo fum)))
'(FEE FI)
[78]> (cdr '(FEE FI))
(FI)
```

the last call should have been

```
[1]> (cdr (quote '(FEE FI)))
((FEE FI))
```

Putting `'(FEE FI)` inside the `quote` form prevents its evaluation, so it is passed *as is* to `cdr`. Here's how we can be sure about this:

```
[2]> (car '('(fee fi) '(fo fum)))
'(FEE FI)
[3]> (cdr *)     ; * is the last returned value
((FEE FI))
```

`(cdr (car ...))` really *is* `cdar`, no question about it.